# bindings in my WPF combobox are not working?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a ListView which displays an image, two textboxes, and a combobox.
The ListView is bound to a collection in my view model.
The Combobox is bound to yet another collection in my view model and the selected item is bound to the property in the object in the listview.
Expected results : for each item the combobox would display the value from the current image.  The user should then be able to choose a new value in the dropdown and it gets assigned to the image object.

What I get: a blank combobox!  When I click the v it shows all of the items with no Name displayed!

My view model (it has to live within the constructs of our current application design) I removed the commands for brevity.  The Items is the collection bound to the ListView and the ArtifactTypes are the list of items of which one is set for the object in the ListView.

```
    [AssociatedView(typeof(ManageImageView))]
public class ManageImagesViewModel : ClosableViewModelBase
{
    private Guid jobid;
    private TSObservableCollection<MobileImage> items = new TSObservableCollection<MobileImage>();
    private TSObservableCollection<ArtifactType> artifactTypes = new TSObservableCollection<ArtifactType>();

    public TSObservableCollection<MobileImage> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return items;
        }
        set
        {
            items = value;
        }
    }
    public TSObservableCollection<ArtifactType> ArtifactTypes
    {
        get
        {
            return artifactTypes;
        }
        set
        {
            if (artifactTypes != value)
                artifactTypes = value;
        }
    }

    public override string Title
    {
        get { return "Add and Delete Images"; }
    }

    public ManageImagesViewModel(IUnityContainer container)
        : base(container)
    {
        AddImage = new SimpleCommand(HandleAddImage);
        UpdateAll = new SimpleCommand(HandleUpdateAll);
        ExitRequest = new SimpleCommand(HandleExitProcess);
        DeleteCommand = new SimpleGenericCommand<Guid>(HandleDeleteProcess);
        List<ArtifactTypeDto> types = BusinessEngine.Mobile.GetTypeDefinitions();
        foreach (ArtifactTypeDto element in types)
        {
            ArtifactTypes.Add(new ArtifactType(element.Name, element.ArtifactTypeId));
        }
    }
```

And my view definition:

```
            <ListView Width="510" MinHeight="600" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="4" Height="160" Width="Auto">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="160"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="42" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="42" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image, Mode=OneWay}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="4" Height="150" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" FontWeight="Bold" MinWidth="250" FontSize="12"/>
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding Path=Comment, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="12" />
                        <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" ItemsSource="{Binding ArtifactTypes, Mode=OneTime}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Key" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ArtifactTypeIdentity, Mode=TwoWay}" FontSize="12"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=ArtifactIdentity}">
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Image Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="24" Width="24" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="pack://application:,,,/SERVPRO.WorkCenter.Common.UI;component/Images/DeleteRed.png"/>
                            </Button.Content>
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Finally -- here is the definition of the values for populating the combobox:

```
    public class ArtifactType:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ArtifactType(string name, Guid value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Key = value;
    }

    private string name;
    private Guid key;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public Guid Key
    {
        get { return key; }
        set 
        {
            if (key != value)
            {
                key = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Key");
            }
        }
    }

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string p)
    {
        if ( PropertyChanged != null )
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

So does anyone see in my bindings WHY I get a blank combobox list?  (The TSObservableCollection is our thread safe ObservableCollection for handling updating the collection when not on the UI thread but with the UI being notified of the change.)

Comment: What does it say if you add PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High in your ItemsSource binding? I can't see a problem otherwise. Are you sure you aren't resetting ArtifactTypes in the view model? Remove the setter to ArtifactTypes if you don't use it, otherwise add a PropertyChanged notification here aswell. Try to use [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to find a problem in your ui.

Comment: have a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial

Comment: Thanks Rachel but I understand the basics of MVVM.  It was just addressing the two heirarchical levels of where the data was coming from.  So when are you moving to Nashville and marrying me?  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the Output window while you are running in Visual Studio, you should see that there is a Binding error.

The way you have your binding set, it is looking for ArtifactTypes as a property of Items, not of your ViewModel, because it is part of the ItemTemplate that Items defines.

Try something like this:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ArtifactTypes, Mode=OneTime, 
              RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"
```

What that does is binds the ItemsSource to the ArtifactTypes property of the DataContext of the ListView.  That DataContext is your ViewModel.

Comment: Wonko the Sane -- I love your name!!!   I figured that it was confused between the ListView source and the DataContext source be really had no idea how to address it!  Thank you so much.  Works like snot on squeaky hinges.  :)

Comment: Yeah - bindings can be pesky critters